# No wifi after kernel upgrade to 4.15 OR 4.16

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, modprobe

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have this network card: https://www.tp-link.com/uk/products/details/cat-11_Archer-T6E.html

With kernel 4.14.x everything is working just fine. But when upgrading to 4.15.x or 4.16, I can not see any wifi connections. But I can get a temporary connection through my phone's usb.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` returns

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
Kernel modules: bcma
```

When I try to do `modprobe wl`

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.16.0-041600-generic
```

I have tried reinstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source`

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

But this leads to

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:


bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,064 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2 [1,544 kB]
Fetched 1,544 kB in 0s (2,774 kB/s)           
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 499695 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.16.0-041600-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.16.0-041600-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.16.0-041600-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.16.0-041600-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.16.0-041600-generic
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-041600-generic
```

And here is the output of `/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log`

https://pastebin.com/UP4Gm1Td

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1757008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is quite obvious. The Broadcom proprietary drivers don't build for the latest kernels.

Also the 4.15 and 4.16 kernels are not officially supported by Ubuntu.

You can try the driver from the 18.04 Ubuntu release
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb

It may build for the 4.15 kernel.

Comment: So I just have to wait then? :)

Comment: Yes, wait and hope that Broadcom will update the drivers. Or some patch will be issued to the open-source part of the driver.

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen I updated the answer. You can try the driver from bionic.

Comment: Well, now I've drilled a hole in the wall, and using cable now :D

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen i think this is the best solution for now.

Comment: here is a fix btw: https://askubuntu.com/a/1052418/308869

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Xenial 16.04, tested with [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021271/67871) answer.
I do not replace my deb-package with Bionic version, instead I just extract files needed (3 files exactly):

```
T=$(mktemp -d)
dpkg-deb bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb $T
cd $T
cat << EOF | xargs -i echo sudo cp -avi {} /{}
usr/src/bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom/patches/0026-add-support-for-Linux-4.15.patch
usr/src/bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom/patches/0025-add-support-for-Linux-4.14.patch
usr/src/bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom/dkms.conf
EOF
# I just echo the "sudo cp" cmds. Double check and exec manually
# Complete with: rm -Rfv $T
```

Then rebuild dkms

```
for k in $(ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools) ; do
for d in $(cd /usr/src; ls -d *-*) ; do
 [[ -f /usr/src/${d}/dkms.conf ]] || continue
 m=$(echo $d | sed -r -e 's/-([0-9]).+//')
 v=$(echo $d | sed -r -e 's/[^0-9]+-([0-9])/\1/')
 sudo /usr/sbin/dkms install -c /usr/src/$d/dkms.conf -m $m -v $v -k $k
done
done
```