# Wifi stops working after an update on ubuntu 16.04 - on Lenovo B590

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, update-manager

When I try this command

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

it show something like

### *-network UNCLAIMED

Edit after running diagnosis

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Jul 2018 21:21 IST +0530

Booted last: 28 Jul 2018 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:5002]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0294 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:1002 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:7436 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s20u4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s20u4' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.222  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cb3d:3414:8998:83c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1199305 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:271948 (271.9 KB)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:41725 (41.7 KB)  TX bytes:41725 (41.7 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s20u4  no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20u4
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s20u4
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s20u4

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       847     1  0 21:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20u4
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Lenovo
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Lenovo
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20u4' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/net/enp0s20u4
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20u4
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ea8a2cb9-760b-3599-86e1-b3ed35228094
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{4}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ea8a2cb9-760b-3599-86e1-b3ed35228094 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.222/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.222
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1532796413
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = batman-Lenovo-B590
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::cb3d:3414:8998:83c2/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/net/enp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Thoughtclan-Wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Thoughtclan-Wifi | type=wifi | permissions=user:batman:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Thoughtclan-Wifi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Lenovo VIBE K4 Note]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Lenovo VIBE K4 Note | type=wifi | permissions=user:batman:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Lenovo VIBE K4 Note
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIR-825]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIR-825 | type=wifi | permissions=user:batman:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DIR-825
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Vinayaka pg 3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Vinayaka pg 3 | type=wifi | permissions=user:batman:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Vinayaka pg 3
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s20u4  no frequency information.

enp4s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp0s20u4  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   16.724589] rndis_host 3-4:1.0 enp0s20u4: renamed from usb0
[   22.203435] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u4: link is not ready
[   22.206914] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[   22.458215] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: link down
[   22.458291] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Hello sopan mittal, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is **ask** a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. Is the error message unexpected?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have edited my question please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix Broadcom driver Wifi with 4.15.0-xx kernel on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052403/how-can-i-fix-broadcom-driver-wifi-with-4-15-0-xx-kernel-on-ubuntu-16-04)